# Java Nashorn JSObject set function as member

Tags: java, nashorn

im using the nashorn script engine and have a problem with the JSObject interface.
I've create a base class to add functions manuelly to the JSObject via a HashMap for the members:

```
public abstract class EngineObject extends AbstractJSObject {
    private Map<String, Object> members;

    public EngineObject() {
        this.members = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public abstract String getName();

    public void initialize(Engine engine) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getMember(String name) {
        return this.members.get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMember(String name, Object value) {
        this.members.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMember(String name) {
        return this.members.containsKey(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeMember(String name) {
        this.members.remove(name);
    }
}



public class MyObject extends EngineObject {
    this.setMember("test", (Runnable) () -> {
        System.out.println("Test");
    });
}

//JavaScript - works
MyObject.test.run();

//JavaScript -- doesn't work
MyObject.test();
```

How can i add a function to the hashmap that javascript recognize it as a function?
And how can i invoke a function via getMember (from the HashMap)?

Comment: Adding a Runnable using setMember should work. Unfortunately the code you have posted is rather incomplete and has bad syntax, so probably nobody can tell what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by "aventurin" your idea is right - but your code is incomplete. Simple compilable, runnable example:

```
import javax.script.*;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.*;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       JSObject jsobj = new AbstractJSObject() {
           @Override
           public Object getMember(String name) {
               // return a Runnable for "func"
               if (name.equals("func")) {
                  return new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                         System.out.println("in run!");
                      }
                  };
               }
               return null;
           }
       };

       ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
       ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");
       e.put("obj", jsobj);
       e.eval("obj.func()");
   }
}
```